# what does .NET SDK and .NET runtime actually contain?

Tags: c#, .net, sdk

Below is my assumptions and questions, please correct me if I'm wrong

1.NET Runtime is CLR which executes Common Intermediate Language (CIL) byte code and does garbage collection etc. Without .NET Runtime, we cannot run any .net programs

2.NET SDK contains anything that required to build/develop .net program. that's why when we install an IDE like VS, it includes .NET SDK (which includes .NET Runtime as well)

3.does it mean that .NET SDK contain compiler and linker?

4.does .NET Runtime contain loader?

5.are essential dlls like MSCorLib.dll included in .NET SDK?

Comment: *(From memory - it's been a while)* The runtime actually contains the C# and VB compilers, some of the CLR components require that the compiler be available. There is no linker. But, you are right, the runtime is what you need to run programs.  It includes the core parts (that load things up, do garbage collection, interact with the OS, etc.)  as well as the full set of standard System.* assemblies. The MSCorLib assembly is definitely part of the runtime.  The SDK includes programmer-oriented tools as well as samples, etc.  The runtime is focused on users, the SDK on programmers

Answer (score 0):

1. True
2. True
3. True
4. True
5. True

SDK includes everything that Runtime has.

I recommend you this book "CLR via C#"  [https://www.amazon.com/CLR-via-4th-Developer-Reference/dp/0735667454](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735667454)

Comment: are dlls like MSCorLib.dll included in .NET SDK or .NET Runtime, since dlls are dynamically loaded.

Comment: DLLs are included both SDK and Runtime. Extra tools like "IL Disassembler" are included in SDK.  DLLs are dynmically loaded. If your app uses a DLL then it is loaded into RAM.

Comment: @secondImage: Nothing will run without MSCorLib; it's definitely included in the runtime.  But, as I mentioned above, so are the compilers. I'm curious, why are you asking?  The SDK and some editions of Visual Studio are free.  Visual Studio provides you tools for packaging your application in a way that will have it run on any appropriate platform that has the runtime installed.  In general, you don't have to worry very much about this.